# jQuery/Javascript can't access information about elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, styles

There seems to be a problem with my DOM, in that the style of elements are all appearing blank.

My jQuery is simply

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#mainContent).css("min-height", function(){
        return $(window).height() + 'px';
    });
});
```

Nothing happens on page load.

I suspect there is not a problem with the syntax, or if there is, this is not what is causing my problem. I have tried to script this myself in javascript and it yielded similar results which is why I turned to jQuery in the first place.

if I

```
alert("text")
```

it works fine but if I try

```
$(#mainContent).css("min-height")
```

then nothing happens.

I have, in a separate javascript file created a variable which is simply

```
var mainCon = document.getElementById("mainContent");
```

and using firebug, put a breakpoint in after the variable is declared, then when inspecting the variable using firebug, everything within styles is blank, eg

```
height ""
width ""
color ""
```

etc.

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this problem and I am losing sleep over it, I have scraped the hell out of google and can't seem to find anything relevant.

Any help you can find will be massively appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [quote your selectors](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) (specifically `#mainContent`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainContent").css("min-height", function(){
        return $(window).height() + 'px';
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe that worked and I can't believe I didn't notice that. That's what sleep deprivation does I guess. Well thanks so much for noticing that. It does in fact appear to have solved my issue.

Just out of curiosity, have you any idea why the styles appear blank in javascript when I inspect with firebug?

Comment: @RichieVikinglordTerry: No problem at all! Sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes `:)`

Comment: You also need to change the function to just `$(window).height() + 'px'`.

Comment: @mc10: That would work, but isn't his problem--The `css` function also accepts a function as it's second argument.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Gah thanks for telling me that. There's no point of my edit then.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing quotes in the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainContent').css("min-height", function(){
        return $(window).height() + 'px';
    });
});
```